# What code to check if 2 time periods overlap?

Tags: java

I want to compare 2 Period Objects using the (PeriodAStart < PeriodBEnd+1 && PeriodAEnd+1 > PeriodBStart) method to check for overlap and 1 day after the last period.

```
LocalDate in = LocalDate.of(inYear, inMonth, inDay);
LocalDate out = LocalDate.of(outYear, outMonth, outDay);

if(checkAvailability(in, out)){
     Reservation newRes = new Reservation(in, out, rooms);
}

//

public static boolean checkAvailability(LocalDate in, LocalDate out) {
    FileManager.openCalendarFile();
    ArrayList<Calendar> caList = new ArrayList<>();
    caList = FileManager.getCalendar();
    boolean overlap = true;

    Period p = Period.between(in, out);

    for(Calendar cal : caList) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue you're running into?

Comment: I should have been more specific sorry. I want to know how to get "start" and "end" values of a period, or if it's possible at all with the Period class. Alternatives maybe?

Comment: No, you can't. A Period is not an interval between two dates. It's an amount of time. read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are checking if `Calendar` objects fall into your `Period`.

`Calendar` is a bad API. If possible, I suggest that you change `FileManager.getCalendar()` to return a `LocalDate`.

Also, a `Period` represents things like "5 months" and "7 years". It does not have a  start and end.

You should convert your `Calendar` to a `LocalDate` first:

```
// write this in the for loop
LocalDate date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(cal.toInstant(), cal.getTimeZone().toZoneId()).toLocalDate();
```

And then, call `isAfter` and `isBefore`:

```
if (out.isAfterDate(date) && in.isBefore(date)) {
    // the date falls between in and out.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @Mark too. I removed all instances of the Calendar class and replaced them with LocalTime instead. New boolean reads: 

`in.isBefore(cal.getCheckOut().plusDays(1)) && out.plusDays(1).isAfter(cal.getCheckIn())`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using period however you can do something like this:

```
LocalDate in = LocalDate.now().minusDays(100);
LocalDate out = LocalDate.now().plusDays(100);

LocalDate dateToCheck = LocalDate.now();

if (in.isBefore(dateToCheck) && out.isAfter(dateToCheck)) {
    System.out.println("dateToCheck within period of in-out");

}
```

In this example I take today as the `dateToCheck`, `in` as 100 days before today and `out` 100 days after today. The code above will print `dateToCheck within period of in-out` since `dateToCheck` is within that 'period'.